# Un frame layout que muestre exactamente lo mismo que el otro

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, android-layout

Me refiero a mostarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
Mainlayout2.addView(Mainlayout);
```

Tomen en cuenta que a la primera vista se le añadió la vista de la cámara en tiempo real...

Mi objetivo en si es buscar la manera de mostrar en otro `framelayout` lo que está en el primero pero sin llamar a los procedimientos del primero. Solo crear un clon de lo que se visualiza...

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que hay algo importante que considerar:

> a la primera vista se le añadió la vista de la cámara en tiempo real

Si te refieres a cargar la imagen de la cámara (frontal o trasera) en otro `FrameLayout` no puedes realizarlo, tienes que considerar que el streaming se relaciona a un único [`SurfaceView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) que seguramente es lo que utilizas. Tal vez podrías agregar la vista pero no se podría ver la imagen!.